# How to respond asynchronously in Google Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I wrote a function which's goal is to send a user order information to a Payment Processor and return the response from the Payment Processor to the user.

However my function always returns NULL instead of waiting for the response from the Payment Processor (MercadoPago). I have been reading about Prosmises but I have not been able to grasp how to make them work.

This is my current code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var mercadopago = require('mercadopago');

exports.getPreference = functions.https.onCall((request, response) => {
    mercadopago.configure({
        access_token: 'TEST-1018285142710709-022320-8093c7aa4c51c987e9698e3a6299bd48-185883176'
    });

    var preference = {}

    var item = {
      title: 'Bottle',
      quantity: 7,
      currency_id: 'ARS',
      unit_price: 95.99
    }

    var payer = {
      email: "demo@mail.com"
    }

    preference.items = [item]
    preference.payer = payer

    mercadopago.preferences.create(preference).then(function (data) {
        return data
     }).catch(function (error) {
        return error.message
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return something from the top level function, not from within a callback to some other method.

If you want to return the object yielded by the call to "mercadopago", then return its promise:

```
return mercadopago.preferences.create(preference)
```